# Indigo on Raspberry/Debian - dependency problem / catkin error

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, raspbian, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,
I try to get Indigo work on the raasberry pi (raspbian) and get the same probems as mentioned here: http://answers.ros.org/question/192250/raspberry-pi-with-ros-indigo-or-any-new-release-of-ros/ As there is no solution yet, I post some more details, maybe someone can help:
I'm following the steps from the tutorial here: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source.

With the following command, I get the dependency problem:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/ros_catkin_ws $ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y --os=debian:wheezy
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
roslisp: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]
collada_parser: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS [debian]
rosconsole_bridge: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]
class_loader: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]
urdf: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS [debian]
collada_urdf: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS [debian]
urdf_parser_plugin: No definition of [liburdfdom-headers-dev] for OS [debian]
cpp_common: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]
geometric_shapes: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]
rosbag_storage: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]
tf2: No definition of [libconsole-bridge-dev] for OS [debian]
```

Is there a way to get this solved? I also tryed to install the packages with apt-get, but could not find a source that provides the packages for raspberry pi. And I found that manual installation of the armhf packages from sides like https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libconsole-bridge-dev does not work, as the dependencies go on and on forever...
Then I red that I could just skip the step above, so I went on to the next step and get the error as follows. Is this error maybe due to some other root cause, and can someone help to solve this? Thanks for any help :-):

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/ros_catkin_ws $ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo
Base path: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated
Devel space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated
Install space: /opt/ros/indigo
Additional CMake Arguments: -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~  traversing 49 packages in topological order:
~~  - catkin
~~  - genmsg
...(list is shortened by me)...
~~  - topic_tools
~~  - rosbag
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin'
==> cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated        /catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release in '/home        /pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
Unhandled exception of type 'OSError':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 875, in build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 627, in build_package
    destdir=destdir
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 386, in build_catkin_package
    run_command_colorized(cmake_cmd, build_dir, quiet, add_env=add_env)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 181, in run_command_colorized
    run_command(cmd, cwd, quiet=quiet, colorize=True, add_env=add_env)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 199, in run_command
    raise OSError("Failed command '%s': %s" % (cmd, e))
OSError: Failed command '['cmake', '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home        /pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo',     '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
<== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
  Failed command '['cmake', '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws    /devel_isolated/catkin', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo',         '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194645/indigo-on-raspberry/debian---dependency-problem-/-catkin-error/) by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was also trying to get Indigo installed on the Raspberry Pi and I think I've gotten it figured out.  Rosdep needed a few new rules since packages like `libconsole-bridge-dev` have now been released separately from ROS.  I've written [installation instructions for the Raspberry Pi on Indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi), so I'd appreciate if you could try it out and let me know if there are any problems.

(Note that as of 10/2014, `libconsole-bridge-dev` and `liburdfdom-dev` haven't made it yet to wheezy, only jessie, so they need to be installed from source - the directions for this are in the installation instructions)

---

Originally posted by [awilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4577/awilson/) with karma: 231 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-10-23**:
Oh wow, thanks very very much!! The instructions look quite detailed, I will check it in the next days and come back! Thanks again :-)

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-10-24**:
It all works perfectly, thanks a lot!! I installed ros_comm version. Only comment is that the ros_comm version besides the libconsole-bridge-dev also needs the liblz4-dev. Thanks agin, I would not have made it on my own :-)!

**Comment by [awilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4577/awilson/) on 2014-10-24**:
Thanks for the info!  I've updated the instructions to fix that.

**Comment by [Tanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/22604/tanvir/) on 2015-05-31**:
Hi, while installing liburdfdom-headers-dev, I forgot to change the name. Is there any way to undo the install, as reinstalling it is leading to some overwrite errors.
Thanks

**Comment by [awilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4577/awilson/) on 2015-06-04**:
You should be able to remove the package by running `dpkg -r urdfdom-headers` and then reinstall using the correct name with checkinstall.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try building without the `--install-space /opt/ros/indigo` option and move the files after. The build might not have write permissions to create the folder.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on 2014-10-10**:
Thanks for this idea, I tryed already, but it did not help...